# (installshield) I want to know how to run regardless of the files in the package program

Tags: installshield-2010

I used installshield 2010 to create a package distribution file. The distribution file contains the Teamviwerqc.exe file. The problem is
the latest Windows 10 1803 update seems to have affected the package of my program.

When I run the program, reinstallation window is looking for the .msi file.
However, if I run Teamviewrqs.exe the same thing happens, too. The Teamviewrqs.exe file runs independently, regardless of the package of program and only the shortcuts are created on the desktop.

Is there an option in installshield that makes it executable regardless of the package program?